# How to use SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT and also set a photo for the contact?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-bitmap

### Background

I know that there are various fields that can be set via this intent, such as address, phone numbers, name, etc... :

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, Uri.parse("tel:" +PhoneNumberService.formatNumber(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL));
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, name);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL_ISPRIMARY,address);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL,address);
... //other stuff, like on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3456319/878126
```

### The problem

I'd like to know if it's possible to also add a photo.

### What I've tried

I've tried the next code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap == null || bitmap.isRecycled())
        return null;
    final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    final byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}


final byte[] imageByteArray = toByteArray(mBitmap);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, imageByteArray);
```

### The question

Is it possible to put the photo too? If so, how?

I've also tried to figure out if the adding has succeeded, so that I could get the contact-key and be able to modify it if I will need to, but it seems that "startActivityForResult" doesn't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

No.

The `SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT` intent starts the [`ShowOrCreateActivity`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/6b73f40ae214d66111e5b4cdbe58fd16afef0fdc/src/com/android/contacts/activities/ShowOrCreateActivity.java).
And from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.html#SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT):

> Any extras from the `ContactsContract.Intents.Insert` class will be passed along to the create activity if there are no contacts to show.

So `ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL` should work, but there is really no reason why `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo` might work.

### Long Answer

From the code, the previous activity searches for the contact by phone if the Uri is `tel:` or email if it is `mailto:`, and if none is found, [prompts the user](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/6b73f40ae214d66111e5b4cdbe58fd16afef0fdc/src/com/android/contacts/activities/ShowOrCreateActivity.java#L207) and the positive button starts createIntent.

```
            final Intent createIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
            createIntent.putExtras(mCreateExtras);
            createIntent.setType(RawContacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
```

where the `mCreateExtras` contains all extras you passed to `SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT` (see [`onCreate`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/6b73f40ae214d66111e5b4cdbe58fd16afef0fdc/src/com/android/contacts/activities/ShowOrCreateActivity.java#L110))

[According to the AndroidManifest](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/6b73f40ae214d66111e5b4cdbe58fd16afef0fdc/AndroidManifest.xml#L345), this starts a `ContactEditorActivity` which sets up a toolbar and places a [`ContactEditorFragement`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/6b73f40ae214d66111e5b4cdbe58fd16afef0fdc/src/com/android/contacts/editor/ContactEditorFragment.java).

The journey is almost over. The data binding is done in [bindEditorsForNewContact()](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/6b73f40ae214d66111e5b4cdbe58fd16afef0fdc/src/com/android/contacts/editor/ContactEditorFragment.java#L769) and seems limited to what [RawContactModifier.parseExtras()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2_r1/com/android/contacts/model/RawContactModifier.java#526) provides. The documentation seems correct.

### Workaround

However, there is another way to insert a contact, directly with the content provider.

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
 values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
 // This may work (not tested)
 values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, imageByteArray);
 Uri rawContactUri = getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.CONTENT_URI, values);
 long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
```

So what you could do is:

1. Help the user to create a contact by starting the SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT
2. Once the contact has been created, insert a display photo for this contact.

Comment: so it is impossible, right? What you suggest is to code the part of putting the entire data into a contact , and maybe even create a UI for the user, meaning to replace the built in activity that deals with it. I don't understand the second solution you've suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is. If you want to help the user create a contact, the workaround could be to create the contact without the display picture first, and add a display picture once it has been created.

Comment: So there isn't an official way to do it?

Comment: ok, because it's not available and impossible to use, I've made a request: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=171372

Comment: But I still wish to know if it's possible to know whether the insertion has finished with success or not.

Comment: @androiddeveloper the only way for you to get a result would be through `onActivityResult`, just check if it returns anything and you'll have your answer.

Comment: @Alex.F It doesn't work. Using startActivityForResult and then onActivityResult, it always sets resultCode to 0 , which is RESULT_CANCELED

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if you found a working answer for this. I would have commented but i don't have enough points.I am also still looking for a good answer.

From the documentation, new contact inserts cannot be created explicitly. That means that a new contact data needs to be inserted using a URI and values(implicitly).

The only possible way is to create a new contact using the content provider and add all fields including default image. Then immediately after, use ACTION_EDIT to let user edit the fields.

Look also into Intents.ATTACH_IMAGE

Comment: That's what I did eventually.