# How to edit and/or view a contact that's was just been inserted?

Tags: android, android-intent, insert, android-contacts

### Background

I need to be able to create a contact with a photo. Since I've found that it's impossible to do via a normal intent ([**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888369/how-to-use-show-or-create-contact-and-also-set-a-photo-for-the-contact)), I've decided that instead, I'll create the contact myself (with the photo), and then go to the contact's details screen (of what the OS has to show).

### The problem

I can't figure out which intent should be used (and how) to reach the contacts screen, whether it would be for editing or viewing it, after creating the contact.

### The code

I use this code to create a new contact (based on [**this website**](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/programatically-adding-contacts-with-photo-using-contacts-provider-in-android-example/)) :

```
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
            int rawContactID = 0;

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                    .build());
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contactName)
                    .build());
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber)
                    .withValue(Phone.TYPE, CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .build());
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, stream.toByteArray())
                        .build());
                try {
                    stream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Uri uri=null;
            try {
                final ContentProviderResult[] contentProviderResults = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                uri = contentProviderResults[0].uri;
                // what to do here ?
            } catch (OperationApplicationException | RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

### What I've tried

I tried using the next types of intents :

- ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT
- Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT
- Intent.VIEW
- Intent.EDIT

I've noticed that some intents work on one device but won't on another, but it could be that I just use them wrong.

### The question

Once I have the Uri of the insertion, what can I do to go to the contact's details screen?

Also, is my code of insertion ok? It seems odd for me that "rawContactID" is 0...

---

EDIT: I've found a weird solution (by testing things), but I can't find why it's this way.

Now my question is: Am I correct in this? Is this code safe now? Would it work on all devices and Android versions well and not crash? Is there maybe some documentation about this behavior ?

Here's the new extra code:

```
...

try {
    final ContentProviderResult[] contentProviderResults = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    Uri uri = contentProviderResults[contentProviderResults.length - 1].uri;
    Cursor contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{Contacts._ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY}, null, null, null);
    if (contactCursor != null && contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        long contactId = contactCursor.getLong(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));
        String contactKey = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        contactCursor.close();
        contactCursor = null;
        final Intent intent = ThirdPartyIntentsUtil.prepareContactIntent(SearchContactDetailsActivity.this, contactId, contactKey, true);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (contactCursor != null)
        contactCursor.close();
} catch (OperationApplicationException | RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


...

/**
 * prepares an intent to go to the contact's page on the address book
 *
 * @param justView true if you wish to just view the contact, false if you wish to edit it
 * @return an intent for edit/view a contact, or null if it's not possible
 */
public static
@Nullable
Intent prepareContactIntent(@NonNull Context context, final long contactId, @NonNull final String contactLookupKey, final boolean justView) {
    final Uri selectedContactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, contactLookupKey);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(justView ? Intent.ACTION_VIEW : Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setDataAndType(selectedContactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final ResolveInfo resolveActivity = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
            | PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
    return resolveActivity == null ? null : intent;
}
```